# Is the alternative operator in ABNF match first or longest?

Tags: grammar, iso, peg, abnf

ISO 5234 says:

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5234#section-3.2

> Elements separated by a forward slash ("/") are alternatives.    Therefore,
>
> ```
>      foo / bar
> ```
>
> will accept <foo> or <bar>.

Using ISO 3339 for the ABNF definition for ISO 8601 datetime you have lines like

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3339#appendix-A

> ```
>    date-century      = 2DIGIT
>    date-decade       =  DIGIT  ; 0-9
>    date-subdecade    =  DIGIT  ; 0-9
>    date-year         = date-decade date-subdecade
>    dateopt-century   = "-" / date-century
>    datespec-year     = date-century / dateopt-century date-year
> ```

If you assume alternatives imply match first, `2024` would only match on `20` and ignore the rest. If you assume alternatives imply match longest, `2024` would match in it's entirety.

Based on that, it seems almost safe to assume that alternatives are indeed match longest. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the alternative operator in ABNF match first or longest?

It's neither.

BNF and its variants specify context free grammars. Unlike parsing expression grammars, context free grammars do not have a concept of ordered choice. There's no priority between alternatives, you choose whichever one leads to a successful parse.

So let's say you have the following production:

```
start = foo bar
foo = "A" / "AB"
bar = "C" / "BD"
```

If we went with a "match first" strategy, the input "ABBD" would not be accepted because `foo` would only match "A" and the "BBD" left over could not be matched by `bar`. That's what would happen with a PEG, but for a CFG, "ABBD" is a word in the language defined by the above grammar.

If we went with a "match longest" strategy, the input "ABD" would not be accepted because `foo` would match "AB", leaving a single "D" that couldn't be matched by `bar`. But again, "ABD" is part of the language, so we can't use that strategy either.

The rule for context free grammars is that a word is part of the language if there exists any sequence of derivations that would derive the word from the grammar and there's no restrictions on which alternatives you're allowed to pick to come up with such a sequence.

Comment: Thanks, that explains why things didn't parse like i thought they would. I was using pyparsing which is peg. Need to find a different lib.